# How to set background image to a shape

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, background-image

I am new to Xamarin Forms, I am from WPF background. In WPF it's easy to set background image(remote) to a shape. Is there any equivalent thing in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Transformations-Guide

Answer (score 2):

After Shapes and Paths were introduced to Xamarin.Forms you can achieve it inside a Grid:

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Ellipse Stroke="blue" StrokeThickness="5" Fill="Black" Aspect="Fill"/>
    <Image Source="xamarin.png" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

---

Rounded corners with `Frame`:

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Frame WidthRequest="200" CornerRadius="80"
           BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="200"/>
    <Image Source="xamarin.png" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

---

Using `Path`:

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Path Stroke="blue"
          Data="m123.87668,219.80811l21.30223,-42.92685l36.89384,-24.78565l42.60447,0l36.89384,24.78565l21.30223,42.92685l0,49.57131l-21.30223,42.92685l-36.89384,24.78564l-42.60447,0l-36.89384,-24.78564l-21.30223,-42.92685l0,-49.57131z"
          StrokeThickness="5" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200"
          Aspect="Fill" Fill="Black"/>

    <Image Source="xamarin.png" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

---

#### Related Documentation

- Microsoft Blog: [Drawing UI with Xamarin.Forms Shapes and Paths](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-shapes-and-paths/).
- Microsoft Official documentation: [Xamarin.Forms Shapes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/).
- GitHub: Specifications: [Shapes & Paths](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9178)